# Attribute Error: list object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-3.7, attributeerror

```
time_weight = list(100*np.exp(np.linspace(-1/divisor, -(num_steps-1)/divisor, num_steps))).apply(lambda x:int(x))
```

When I try this, I get the following error in Python 3.7.

> **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'**

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 5):

As the error said, `list` type has no `apply` attribute.
This said, if you have a list `l` and you want to set to `int` type every element in it you may use:

```
l = [int(x) for x in l]
```

or

```
l = list(map(int,l))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `list` has no `apply` method. If what you want to do is convert every element to an `int`, you could remove the lambda function and instead use [`astype(int)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
time_weight = list((100*np.exp(np.linspace(-1/divisor, -(num_steps-1)/divisor, num_steps))).astype(int))
```